# Looping over rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, performance

Suppose I *need* to loop over the rows in a data frame for some reason.

I create a simple data.frame

```
df <- data.frame(id = sample(1e6, 1e7, replace = TRUE))
```

It seems that f2 is much slower than f1, while I expected them to be equivalent.

```
f1 <- function(v){
        for (obs in 1:(1e6) ){
            a <- v[obs] 
        }
        a
    }
system.time(f1(df$id))

f2 <- function(){
        for (obs in 1:(1e6) ){
            a <- df$id[obs] 
        }
    a
    }
system.time(f2())
```

Would you know why? Do they use exactly the same amount of memory?

Comment: With the first function you use `$` once, in the second function you use it 1e6 times. `$` is not the fastest subsetting function.

Comment: What surprises me is that `f1` is twice as fast as `f3 <- function(v)for(a in v){NULL}; system.time(f3(df$id))`. Oh, I see: `1e6` is not the full length of the vector. `system.time(f3(df$id[1:1e6]))` is fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you instead write your timings like this and recognize that `df$x` is really a function call (to `` `$`(df,x) ``) the mystery disappears:

```
system.time(for(i in 1:1e6) df$x)
#    user  system elapsed 
#    8.52    0.00    8.53 
system.time(for(i in 1) df$x)
#    user  system elapsed 
#       0       0       0
```

Answer (score 3):

In `f1`, you bypass the data frame entirely by just passing a vector to your function. So your code is essentially "I have a vector! This is the first element. This is the second element. This is the third..."

By contrast, in `f2`, you give it a whole data frame and then get the each element of a single column each time. So your code is "I have a data frame. This is the first element of the ID column. This is the second element of the ID column. This is the third..."

It's much faster if you extract the simple data structure (vector) once, and then can only work with that, rather than repeatedly extracting the simple structure from the larger object.